# Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to calculate goal difference between goals scored and goals against for each team based on when they're home and away. The problem though is I'm receiving this error:

Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

I commented out the 'Goal_Difference' code and want to know what is causing this issue and it can be fixed. Thank you

```
ALTER VIEW League_Table
AS
SELECT SUM(
    CASE
        WHEN t.TeamID = f.HomeTeamID THEN f.HomeScore
        -- Home Fixture
        WHEN t.TeamID = f.AwayTeamID THEN f.AwayScore
        -- Away Fixture
        END
        ) AS Goals_Scored,

    SUM(
    CASE
        WHEN t.TeamID = f.HomeTeamID THEN f.AwayScore
        -- Home Fixture
        WHEN t.TeamID = f.AwayTeamID THEN HomeScore
        -- Away Fixture
        END
        ) AS Goals_Against
     --   SUM(
        --  CASE
        --  WHEN t.TeamID = f.HomeTeamID THEN       
        --      CASE
        --      WHEN f.HomeScore IS NOT NULL THEN SUM(f.HomeScore) - SUM(f.AwayScore)
        --  -- Home Fixture
        --      END
        --  WHEN t.TeamID = f.AwayTeamID THEN 
        --      CASE
        --      WHEN f.AwayScore IS NOT NULL THEN SUM(f.AwayScore) - SUM(f.HomeScore)
        --  -- Away Fixture
        --      END
        --  END
        --) AS Goal_Difference

FROM dbo.Team t
--Season TBC
INNER JOIN dbo.Fixture f ON t.TeamID IN (f.HomeTeamID, f.AwayTeamID)
GROUP BY t.TeamName


GO

SELECT *  
FROM League_Table lt
ORDER BY Points DESC--, Goal_Difference;
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. You can't use an aggregate inside an aggregate. In your case you should just remove SUM from inside the case expression.

Comment: The commutative properties of addition and subtraction suggest that you don't have to `sum(sum(f1) - sum(f2))`. Just `sum(f1-f2)` and you'll get the same result without having to do illegal double aggregation in your query, or pushing the inside aggregation to a subquery.

Comment: @JNevill though `SUM(f1) + SUM(f2)` can return different results from `SUM(f1 + f2)` if nulls exist.

Comment: That's a whole other issue. You've gotta get the math right, then deal with layer of crap that null values and a relational database introduce. But, I agree. Best coalesce your numeric fields to preserve your sanity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Goal_Difference` to this:

```
        SUM(
      CASE
      WHEN t.TeamID = f.HomeTeamID THEN       
          CASE
          WHEN f.HomeScore IS NOT NULL THEN f.HomeScore - f.AwayScore
      -- Home Fixture
          END
      WHEN t.TeamID = f.AwayTeamID THEN 
          CASE
          WHEN f.AwayScore IS NOT NULL THEN f.AwayScore - f.HomeScore
      -- Away Fixture
          END
      END
    ) AS Goal_Difference
```

If you are summing before the `CASE` , you can't make it sum again in the `WHEN` , that becomes `sum(sum(..` which is not allowed. I assumed that's not what you intended, so I just removed the inner sum.